# How are "strikes" defined for a pitcher?

Tags: baseball, statistics

Strikes have always been tallied for a batter. Since the era of "pitch counts," they have been counted for a pitcher also, to estimate his efficacy.

My understanding is that any pitch in the "strike zone" (over the plate, between the shoulders and the knees), counts as a strike for the pitcher, whether it actually is, is put into play, or is fouled by the batter for "no third strike."

But suppose a pitcher throws a pitch that is objectively a ball (outside of the strike zone). Except that the batter swings with one of the following results: 1) puts the ball in play, 2) swings and misses or fouls for a strike 3) swings for a foul, no "third strike."

Is this pitch counted as a strike under any or all of the above three scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pitcher is credited with a strike in the following circumstances:

- A called strike
- Any pitch where the batter makes contact

A pitcher is credited with a ball in the following circumstances:

- A called ball
- A HBP

That's basically it, those are the four scenarios for a pitch, it's called a ball, it's called a strike, it's contacted by the batter and it hits the batter.

Comment: To be pedantic, the other possibility is "swinging strike".  But that obviously counts as a strike.